# Какой выбрать хостинг для проектов Laravel + Vue (портфолио)?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, хостинг

Делаю проекты на Laravel + Vue (еще вопрос. а стоит ли Vue-проекты закидывать в один хостинг, Github pages для них не пойдет?)
Хочу разместить их в интернете и в портфолио указывать на них ссылки.
Какой хостинг посоветуете? Как можно дешевле (ну и чтобы не висло там ничего, я правда в этом не разбираюсь, но намек я думаю понятен)

Comment: Купи VPS себе: https://www.ovhcloud.com/en/vps/compare

Comment: Просто статику (включая проекты на Vue) можно размещать и на Github Pages. Для похапэ, как ты понимаешь, уже нужен сервер... и общие управляемые хостинги (с панелькой) _не_ рекомендую - там ты как раз найдешь то самое висло :D то есть, норм вариант задешево, это только виртсервер (aka VPS aka VDS). Сам арендую у Hetzner, самый дешевый план CX11 - за примерно 2 года аптайм ровно 100%, диски не тупят, канал не пережимают, и раздражает  только невозможность внести предоплату (чтобы обойти это - создал цифровую Visa для их автоинвойсов и просто раз в полгода пополняю ее). p.s.: там КVM, не OpenVZ.